# What is the easiest way of implementing authentication inside of Telegram WebApp page?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'am writing Telegram Bot with WebApp and want to authenticate user that opened page, so that backend know who is calling API's.
Telegram when I click on WebApp inlineButton opens embedded browser and send to webpage WebAppInitData object with info about user and fields hash to validate data.

Has anybody implemented WebApp authentication to help me with this?
As I see it:

1. User opens WebApp page from telegram
2. webpage receives WebAppInitData object with user info
3. I send this user info to backend, validate hashsum, etc. and authorize user in this session (so all next request will contain user session info)
4. then start rendering page data

am I right? maybe there is simpler way?

I cannot find any example